# Can't see my domain name when using Heroku

Tags: heroku, dns

I got a domain name "raghavkumar.work" from name.com recently and I'm using Heroku servers to run my personal website. I added "www.raghavkumar.work" and "raghavkumar.work" into the custom domain addons in Heroku like so:

[image]

Then I went into name.com and I added three A records that mapped "raghavkumar.work" to three IP Adresses associated with Heroku like this:

[image]

I type in "raghavkumar.work" into my address bar, but it immediately redirects to the heroku app address. Here's what I see in the address bar:

[image]

How can I get my own domain name to show up instead of this annoying heroku app address name? No matter what I do, I can't get my own domain name to show up. It's always redirected to heroku's address. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a CNAME file?

...just a file called CNAME (no extension) with nothing but the bare domain name inside it (raghavkumar.work)...

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

Comment: Yes, I tried that. But I read that CNAME does not allow email functionality. I have a contact page on my website which requires email functionality.

Comment: Nevermind. Using a CNAME actually turned out to be correct after all. Thanks.